# Problem exporting registers with the land registry in DXF continuation (suite) in reprojection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, export

I visualize (display) a municipality with the plugin register with the land registry in spatiality and in projection Lambert 93. I need the bottom on Autocad in projection CC47 thus I re-throw (re-plan) on QGIS by choosing as current SCR the CC47 (the reprojection in the air bustles). Up to there, everything works.

Then, in Project, I choose export DXF and I make my export. It sticks (there is a problem) when I visualize (display) the created file DXF because either I have no object inside, or I have all the municipality but in Lambert 93 (as I mark or not "exporter only the visible entities on the influence of the card (map)").

---

When I make "Project" then "Export DXF", I cannot choose the SCR ( CC47).

Answer (score 2):

Choosing CC47 as **layer** CRS is wrong in most situations, because that has no influence on the coordinates of the layer. So put it back to Lambert 93.

When you export the **layer** to DXF with Rightclick on the layer , `Save As ...`, you can choose CC47 for that DXF, and all coordinates will be reprojected to that CRS.

Note that `Project -> Export to DXF` is a different feature, that does not let you choose the CRS. To use it, all layers should be reprojected to the **project** CRS before.